# How to add a Plus Minus botton in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I would like to have a Plus/Minus button for my Layout in Android (using Java), like the one you can see here https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/99253/plus-minus-button-position-for-selecting-number-of-passengers. Is there a native element in Android for using this? I searched for it but could not find one which surprises me as I'd assume that this is a frequently used element in Apps(at least more frequently used than several items that you can see in the layout editor of Android Studio).

Is there an easy solution for that with native components?
I'd be happy for every comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This thing can be achieved easily with 2 Buttons and one EditText in middle. I used this code in an hotel menu app.

**Use this layout as whole.**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeBtn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_remove"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemQuanEt"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minEms="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/hanken_light"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_add"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

//These are drawables

**custom_btn_add.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_circle_full" />
</selector>
```

**custom_btn_remove.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_remove_circle_outline" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_remove_circle_full" />
</selector>
```

**ic_add_circle_full.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM17,13h-4v4h-2v-4L7,13v-2h4L11,7h2v4h4v2z"/>
</vector>
```

**ic_add_circle_outline.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M13,7h-2v4L7,11v2h4v4h2v-4h4v-2h-4L13,7zM12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.41,0 -8,-3.59 -8,-8s3.59,-8 8,-8 8,3.59 8,8 -3.59,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

**ic_remove_circle_full.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM17,13L7,13v-2h10v2z"/>
</vector>
```

**ic_remove_circle_outline.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M7,11v2h10v-2L7,11zM12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.41,0 -8,-3.59 -8,-8s3.59,-8 8,-8 8,3.59 8,8 -3.59,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

**Edit**
The `dimens` are only margins you define if you want to use them quite often. You can replace that with static values like '16dp'. Also you can change this layout according to you needs too. The main point is to use 2 drawable buttons with an EditText. I changed the code to make it simple for you.

**Edit 2**

I am not much of a master with constraint layout. I tried to just show you an example of how to use this. I still suggest you learn more about how to use constraint in codes rather than just drag and dropping.

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sampleBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sample button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.077"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sampleBtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/removeBtn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_remove"
            android:backgroundTint="#C5BCBC" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/itemQuanEt"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:minEms="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addBtn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_add"
            android:backgroundTint="#C5BCBC" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is an example how to drag it.
[image]

Comment: Thans Zankrut for your answer and the code. It looks quite complicated for me considering that I just want a simple element for counting.

Comment: I tried to use your code inside my Constraint Layout (by copying and pasting it) but I get many errors (in the line with the @ symbol, like "Cannot resolve symbol '@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin' ") and the element is not on the right position.

Comment: Can you use your code inside a Constraint Layout because it seems to cause problems when I put it inside my constraint Layout. I upvoted your answer but still I'd like to know whether there is an easier solution for that because your solution is difficult to work with for beginners. I'd appreciate further feedback. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I changed the code to make it simple and use this whole relative layout as an element in your constraint layout if you want to use this as whole. You can replace with constraint too. But then you might need to work on it more. I mostly use linear or relative layouts for such small views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort Zankrut. How can I use them in a Constraint Layout? When I just copy and past your code the elemnt is just at the top. Normally I just put the constraints in Constrained Layout to the parents such that I can drag and drop the single elements. But with your solution this does not work because the elements themselves are within a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I added a sample code for you to look at. I prefer you start your work with more easy layouts like linear or relative as you sound a beginner in android field. Also try to avoid making designs using dragging views. Working with padding and margin will benefit you in long run. :D

Comment: Thanks Zankrut for your answer and great effort. I really appreciate it. I choose to work with ConstrainedLayout because for me it was simpler and you have way more flexibility than with a linear layout or other layouts. I do not like nested layouts at all. I use the constrained layout by just dragging all the elements to the correct position and then using the 4 constraines to the parents.This way you can just customize your layout easily and it looks good. However if you have elemnts that consist of other elements it sometimes does not work (this is why I want to avoid something like this)

Comment: Thanks Zankrut for your answer and help. I have some questions: 1)Why do you always need 3 XML files for one element (e.g. the remove button)? Can you not just copy them into 1 XML file? 2)Especially I do not understand why you have circle outline and full XML files. Why do you need both of them.  3) Why do you use the path data and not just create an Image with a graphic programm like Inkscape? 4) How did you create the path data?

Comment: It is bad practice to use images in android. Since you need to work with different screens. The outline and full vectors are for pressed and unpressed states. Using the path data vector we can actually resize them and also use tint option to match with app theme. Using shortcuts like a full image of specific dimension look easy but its not good when you run app on multiple screens. You cant change the color of it. You cant change it pressed or unpressed state.

Comment: Thanks Zankrut for your answer and effort. How did you create the pathdata? Do you have a drawing program that outputs them? And basically you can use different images with different resolutions in Android when you store the image in different resolutions like xxxdpi, xdpi, mdpi etc.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222852/how-to-add-a-plus-minus-button-in-android-chat-room message here from now on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222867/discussion-between-zankrut-parmar-and-vanessaf).